# Why This C Code Goes into Loop?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int p()
{
    char data[7]="Hello!\0";
    uint64_t *ptr=((uint64_t)data + 0x18);
    printf("%s",data);
    (*ptr)-=10;
    return 0x00;
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    p();
}
```

Comment: What loop? you mean it hangs forever?

Comment: You have *two* problems, both leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Well actually they are both the same problems, but expressed in two different ways. The problem(s) is that you are writing out of bounds of the `data` array in *two* places.

Comment: And also, the cast `(unit64_t)data`? what does it mean, is it intended?

Comment: My guess is that the code is modifying the stack to alter the return address, casing an infinite loop (jumping to itself). However the way the program accomplish that is by misbehaving and misusing undefined behavior, and it can't be relied upon to work on anything but a few limited systems.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that you don't need to put `\0` when you are declaring a char array like this. The `\0` is automatically placed at the end of the string

Comment: I would generally not advise to use a length for string-initialized char arrays (if not to avoid the 0-terminator). E.g. `char data[6] = "Hello!";` compiles but doesn't 0-terminate. The explicit `\0` prevents that mistake. In this case, omitting both, the explicit length and the `\0` is better, though. If, however, for some reason you insist on the explicit length, explicit `\0` is a good thing IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is undefined behavior.

```
char data[7]="Hello!\0";
```

Writing to the array out of bound leads to undefined behavior.This is not the right way to null terminate a string.You can opt for one of the below options.

Change it to

```
char data[7]="Hello!";
```

You can even have

```
char data[]="Hello!";
```

**Edits:**

By doing this

```
uint64_t *ptr=((uint64_t)data + 0x18);
```

You are making your pointer point to some memory location which is not allocated by you.Later you try to write to this location

```
(*ptr)-=10;
```

So accessing array out of bound or writing to some memory which is not allocated by you leads to undefined behavior.You need to fix them first

Comment: or even better, leave it to the compiler , `char data[ ]="Hello!";`

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yeah I will take that.

Comment: can you explain how this array is goin out of bound... ??

Comment: @RajatVerma The string literal `"Hello!\0"` is a pointer to a constant array of characters containing `'H'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`, `'!'`, `'\0'` and `'\0'`. Adding an explicit `'\0'` to a string doesn't end the string, it just adds another character to the string.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Only if there is space for another 0-terminator. See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673629/why-this-c-code-goes-into-loop#comment45642549_28673629) above.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers and in comments writing `char data[7]="Hello!\0";` could be a problem but I dont think that is the only source of problem here.

My guess is :
`uint64_t *ptr=((uint64_t)data + 0x18);`

`(*ptr)-=10;`
 By doing this probably you are modifying return address from stack or doing something like that.